# Flip card effect failures

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am tying to use a "card flip" type effect using the following code:

CSS

```
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective:800;
    width:278px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative; }

.flip .card.flipped { -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); }

.flip .card {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s; }

.flip .card .face {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden ;
    z-index:2;
    text-align:center; }

.flip .card .front {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer; }

.flip .card .back {
   -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    text-align:center;
    cursor: pointer; }
```

JQUERY SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flip').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="flip"> 
    <div class="card"> 
        <div class="face front"><a href="images/img1.jpg" data-lightbox="data" data-title="title"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="title" /></a></div> 
        <div class="face back">Back content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am facing 2 different issues. This works but does not work as I want it to do... Let me explain.

1. It flips the "card" wherever I click inside the "card" div. How can I make it flip the card but from another div? For example from an image which says "more info" for example, then clicking there, it flips the card.
2. If I click the image contained at the front "card", I cannot use the lightbox effect to show a bigger image as it directly flips the card and doesn't let me do anything else...

I would really appreciate your help guys.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code for using lightbox for your images so that i can modify the content according to your needs

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @avnaveen I don't understand. I am using the lightbox plugin for jQuery (Lightbox v2.7.1 by Lokesh Dhakar - http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using selectors, I have implemented the same functionality for three cards.

In this, I have used `flip_card` as the class name for all the buttons which have their unique id `flip_card_#` something like `flip_card_1` `flip_card_2` `flip_card_3` etc.

These buttons will be used to find the class `flip#` something like `flip1` `flip2` `flip3` and then toggle the class `flipped` for the element with class `card`

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip_card').click(function () {
        var x = $(this).attr("id");
        var i = x.substring(10);
        $('.flip' + i + '').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    });
});
```

> Note: For this code to work, you have to use the numbers accordingly
>   ex. button with an id `flip_card_1` is used to flip the card which is
>   inside an element with a class `flip1`

Please check the modified [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/d5aczgma/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I achieved exactly what I wanted!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your first question is that you have to change your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#flip_card').click(function () {
        $('.flip').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    });
});
```

Instead of using  `$('.flip')` and `$(this)`, I have mentioned the id of the button and the class in which the code has to find the class named 'card'.

> The above code says - When an element with an id '`flip_card`' is
>   clicked, go to the element with a class named `flip`, find the element with a class named `card` and then toggle class `flipped` for that element.

You can directly use something like `$('.card').toggleClass('flipped');`

The code completely depends on how you are going to use it

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/d5aczgma/)

Comment: Thanks, that works great both for question 1 and 2, but what if I want to use a grid of "cards"? Then it flips them all at the same time and i'd like to flip one at a time

Comment: are you going to use multiple buttons to flip multiple cards?

Comment: Yes, ideally one button for each card :)

Comment: If you have an idea on selectors, you can use something like div[class^="flip"] and div[class^="card"] and apply the same css for flip1 flip2, card1, card2 etc.

Similarly, you can use the above selectors and implement the code

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip, that is what I need, that card1 has the same effect as card4. I have no idea on selectors but I will give it a try! Thank you again